# Let $f: [a,b]\to\Bbb R$. If $f$ is continuous at all rational points of $[a,b]$, can we show $f$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f: [a,b]\to\Bbb R$. If $f$ is continuous at all rational points of $[a,b]$, can we show $f$ is bounded?

If $f$ is continuous at all of $[a,b]$, then it is OK. But what if $f$ is continuous at all rational points of $[a,b]$?

Finite covering seems unpleasant.

Comment: If uniformly continuous at all rational, then I bet so.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{2}}&x\ne\sqrt{2}
\\
0&x=\sqrt{2}\end{cases}$$

It is continuous at all rational points, but it is not bounded.

Comment: But $f$ is not defined at $\sqrt{2}$!

Comment: @xldd It is. $f(\sqrt{2})=0$.